# Android included layout shows in preview but not on emulator

Tags: java, android, xml

So, here is the layout I want to include:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/taskTimeSettingName"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:textColor="#7d7d7d"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/remove"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#7d7d7d" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="25"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/add"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#7d7d7d"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#dbdbdb"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/task_time_setting" android:id="@+id/taskTimeSetting" />

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The activity for the parent layout:

```
package ro.nodomain.emil.tasks.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

The layout that I include here shows in inspector but I can't get it to show on the emulator as well. I don't think I messed up the match_parent attributes so that the layout would go off-screen. I wasn't able to find anything online that would help me. What could cause this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error at all. It's just that the layout won't show when I start the app.

Comment: Have you tried using a mobile

Comment: you have not provided constraints to your scrollview. you need to provide them when using constraint layout.

Comment: @KaranMer I did that just now.. nothing changed

Comment: @KaranMer, Yes he should, but with the case of no constraint, element will stick to top left. So OP should still be able to see the element if that was the problem.

Comment: try using a mobile instead of emulator

Comment: @TalhaIsrar Same outcome with a mobile

Comment: Please post the `Activity` class for that layout.

Comment: @Zlytherin I did that already... nothing changes

Comment: Try placing the width attribute of the constraint layout

Comment: @MikeM. I edited my post

Comment: You forgot to call `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` after the `super.onCreate()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. Ok.. that's pretty dumb of me. Thanks for pointing that out. :D It works now